# Is it possible to have Safari automatically close the downloads window when all downloads have completed?

Tags: macos, safari

I miss this feature from Chrome and Firefox.  I can't find it in Safari.  Is it possible to have Safari automatically close the downloads window when all downloads have completed?

Answer (score 1):

[Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) can do that:

> Glims adds a cocktail of features to Safari (More Search Engines, Favicons in tab labels, Chrome bookmarks, Tabs and Bookmarks improvements, Dated download folders ...)